# HTML encoding: when it is used?

Tags: html

what type of encoding is this:

```
&lt;div&gt;&lt;label class=&quot; required&quot;&gt;__name__&lt;/label&gt;&lt;div id=&quot;task_tags___name__&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;label for=&quot;task_tags___name___name&quot; class=&quot; required&quot;&gt;Name&lt;
```

when it is used? what does it serve for?

Comment: Those are HTML entities.

Comment: You could LITERALLY google `&lt;` and you'd have this answer...

Answer (score 2):

That string is just a html string that has special characters escaped. `&lt` becomes `<`, `&gt` becomes `>`. It is just a way to indicate you want to display that character without it rendering as html.

A quick search came up with this [list](http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php?PHPSESSID=8cbbddde9a9c9825467546f1c98fe119) of escape characters

Answer (score 0):

These are html "Special Characters"

Ampersand lt; will appear in a web page as the less than symbol, or < 
Ampersand gt; will show up as >

Ampersand quot; will show up as a quotation mark, etc.

Here's a table of values:

http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

One of the more commonly used ones for me is Ampersand nbsp;  which is "Non Breaking Space."  Sometimes I just want an extra space without cluttering up things with CSS and browsers will normally strip away "extra" whitespace like an extra space.

Answer (score -1):

`htmlentities` for example in php do this, eg. when you need to show some code, what you do not want to render.

```
$string = '<div class="something"></div>';
echo htmlentities($string);
```

Comment: This is not relevant to the question.

Comment: why? "when you need to show some code, what you do not want to render." and i've just give an example.

Comment: This is about a PHP function, when the question is asking what HTML entities are, not how to not render HTML in a PHP echo.